# Android ListView does not display new items

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView which is populated based on the value of the selected RadioButton, with the RadioButtons' OnClick events triggering the ListView to refresh with new values.

I have this almost working, but the issue I have is that if the first RadioButton has 6 items to display in the ListView, then the second clicked RadioButton has 10 items to display, the ListView displays the first 6 items of the 10, then the first 4 items again, as if it's wrapping the items. I am populating the ListView using `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listValues` and a SimpleAdapter and I have checked that listValues does contain 10 distinct values.

The code to display the items is as follows:

```
    ListView listview = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.my_listview);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapt = 
            new SimpleAdapter(getView().getContext(), listValues, 
                               R.layout.my_listitem, 
                               null, null) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            HashMap<String, String> listItem = listValues.get(position);

            View v = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

                TextView nameTextview =
                        (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
                nameTextview.setText(listItem.get("name"));

                TextView detailTextview =
                        (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_textview_2);
                detailTextview.setText(listItem.get("detail"));

                if (listItem.get("main_image") != null) {
                    int imageId = Integer.valueOf(listItem.get("main_image"));
                            (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);
                    image.setImageResource(imageId);
                }
            } 
            return v;
        };
    };

    listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapt);
```

Is there an obvious reason for the repeating list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are handling the getView method is not that efficient. You should give a try to ViewHolder pattern. The Link below is a good practice that you can follow.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Excellent, that's fixed it. I still don't really understand why it was doing that in the first place, but this approach fixes the problem and is also more efficient so I won't spend any more time worrying about it. Thanks!

Comment: The reason is clear, when getView method is called, you are inflating the view you want to attach to the listView but you are inflating the view every single time getView is called. The convert view you are getting from getView method is not always null, so you need to check the convert view before inflating a new one.